# Django - Saving multiple selection boxes in one form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I need to save multiple selections in one form, but it is not saving the values to my model. This is how the form looks:

[image]

This is my models.py

```
class ChoiceManager(models.Manager):
    def rates (self, Task_id, rating2, yo):
        assignment = Assignment.objects.get(id=Assignment_id)
        rating = rating2
        yo = FiscalYear.objects.get(fy_year=years)
        for i in range(len(rating2)):
            rated = Prog_capability.objects.create(
            task = task, 
            rating2 = rating[i],
            fy = yo[i]
        )

class NewYear(models.Model):
    year = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    new_year = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class Choice(models.Model):
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    year = models.ForeignKey(NewYear, related_name="choices")
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, related_name="choice")
    objects = ChoiceManager()
```

This is my views.py

```
def task_rating(request, Assignment_id):
    ratings = request.POST.getlist('rating2',[])
    years= request.POST.getlist('yo",[])
    rates= Choice.objects.rates(Assignment_id, ratings, years)
    return redirect ((reverse('Project:assignment_page', kwargs={'Assignment_id': Assignment_id})))
```

HTML

```
 <form action="{% url 'project:rating' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for year in years %}
        <li class=cap_select>
          <div id=fyc>{{year.fy_year}}</div>
          <select name="rating2" id="{{assignment.id}}-{{year.id}}">
            <option>Choose From List</option>
            <option class=hi value="high">High</option>
            <option class=med value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option class=low value="low">Low</option>
            <option class=na value="n/a">N/A</option>
          </select> 
          <input type="hidden" name="yo" value={{year.fy_year}}>
        </li>  
      {% endfor %}
        <br>
        <input id=save_cap type="submit" value="Save">
      </form>
```

I'm getting a

> "NewYear matching query does not exist." and cannot save the data.

I've been on this for a couple of days. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right

> POST data is not coming as dictionary.

You are looping on years and rendering `select` and `input` tag inside form and the `name` attribute of all `select` and `input` tags are same that is `rating` and `year` simultaneously

in that case when you submit your form you will get a list of `rating` and `year` so you should use `getlist()` method while fetching it from request.POST QueryDict.

```
request.POST.getlist('rating[]')
request.POST.getlist('year[]')
```

if above doesn't work use it like

```
request.POST.getlist('rating', [])
request.POST.getlist('year', [])
```

Update your rates method like.

```
class ChoiceManager(models.Manager):
    def rates (self, Assignment_id, rating, year):
        ...
        # you can use year also to find the length
        for i in range(len(rating)): 
           rated = Choice.create(
              assignment = assignment, 
              year = year[i],
              rating = rating[i]
           )
```

change method call.

```
rates = Choice.objects.rates(Assignment_id,request.POST.getlist('rating[]'), request.POST.getlist('year[]'))
```

Comment: Thanks. Ok. So now I'm getting: ValueError...Cannot assign "[]":"Choice.rating" must be a "Rating" instance. It says the same with both of the getlist you mentioned.

Comment: you need to change your rates  method accordingly

Comment: you are passing list to `rates` and creating choices, but rating and year is foreign key, it will not be assigned  with list.

Comment: How can I save this form then? I'm new to programming. Your patience is much appreciated.

Comment: see you are passing list so before creating Choices object you need to loop over it, so it will create multiple object of choices in your rates method

Comment: I'm sorry to keep bothering you. I understand what you are conveying, but how do I do that?

Comment: Thanks! I have good news and bad news. The good news is that I'm no longer getting any errors. The bad news is that nothing is saving to the database. 
I updated my code above using your suggestions. Did I get something wrong?

Comment: you are using `Prog_capability` model i guess you need to use `Choice`

Comment: My bad. The Prog_capability was a copy/paste mistake. I have it as Choice.objects.create.
As a side note, I really want to thank you for all the help you have given me so far. You are awesome.

Comment: buddy you need to debug that the loop is working or not, if you are using pycharm runserver on debug mode. if not use print statement iniside loop and check if loop is working or not

Comment: also check what is the value return by `request.POST.getlist('rating[]')` and `request.POST.getlist('year[]')` is it blank?

Comment: It's coming in blank "[ ]" from the form to the views

Comment: can you print `request.POST` QueryDict and update your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165480/discussion-between-satendra-and-dev-2018).

Answer (score 0):

So this is what worked in the end:

models.py

```
class ChoiceManager(models.Manager):
def rates (self, Assignment_id, rating2, years, rating_id):
    Assignment = Assignment.objects.get(id=Assignment_id)
    rating = rating2
    rating_id = rating_id
    for i in range(len(rating2)):
        year =NewYear.objects.get(fy_year=years[i])
        rated = Choice.objects.create(
        assignment = assignment, 
        rating = rating[i],
        fy = year,
        rating_id = rating_id[i]
    )
```

views.py

```
def task_rating(request, Assignment_id):
    ratings=  request.POST.getlist('rating2',[])
    years=  request.POST.getlist('yo',[])
    rating_id = request.POST.getlist('rating_id',[])
    rates = Choice.objects.rates(Assignment_id,ratings, years,rating_id)
    return redirect ((reverse('assignment:assignment_page', kwargs={'Assignment_id': Assignement_id})))
```

HTML

```
<form action="{% url 'project:rating' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for year in years %}
      <select name="rating2" id="{{assignment.id}}-{{year.id}}">
        <option>Choose From List</option>
        <option class=hi value="high">High</option>
        <option class=med value="medium">Medium</option>
        <option class=low value="low">Low</option>
        <option class=na value="n/a">N/A</option>
      </select> 
      <input type="hidden" name="yo" value={{year.fy_year}}>
      <input type="hidden" name="rating_id" value="{{tasks.id}}-{{year.id}}">
  {% endfor %}
    <br>
    <input id=save_cap type="submit" value="Save">
  </form>
```